# Show data on SSRS report grouped week or month based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to achieve the appropriate grouping to be shown on `SSRS` report which is driven by the 'weekly' or 'monthly' parameter defined in `SSRS` (not a argument for sproc). For that I'm using following in the Category Groups expression for the field called "Date" (format is '2014-03-01' as example):

```
=IIF(
  Parameters!date_range.value="Weekly", 
  DATEPART("week", Fields!Date.Value),  
  DATEPART("month", Fields!Date.Value)
)
```

This results in the following exception:

> The Value expression for the field ‘Date’ contains an error: Argument
>   'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.
>   (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression). An error has occurred during report
>   processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Why?

Comment: do you have the dateValue field as datetime datatype? Can you convert to datetime type and try again?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is to first of all write your query which pulls forward the results like this.

### SQL Server Query

```
SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Column) AS [Monthly]
       ,DATEPART(WEEK,  Date_Column) AS [Weekly]
       ,SUM(Some_Column)             AS Total
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Column) 
        ,DATEPART(WEEK,  Date_Column)
```

### SSRS Report

Add a Matrix Data region. Drag and drop `Total` column to `DATA`.

Create a Parameter say `GROUP ON` of `Text` type, and provide values

```
1) Weekly
2) Monthly
```

Now below in `ROW GROUPS` pane, right click the only visible Row Group and goto `GROUP PROPERTIES`
In `GROUP ON` section put following expression.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Monthly", Fields!Monthly.Value, Fields!Weekly.Value)
```

Use the exactly same Expression on Data region `ROWS` section.

For Column name you can use the following Expression...

```
=IIF(Parameters!Groupby.Value = "Monthly", "Monthly", "Weekly")
```

and you are good to go.

**Important Note**

SSRS is a cool tool for data presentation, not so cool when it comes to Data manipulation, to get better performance do all sorts of Data Manipulation closer to source (database, SQL Server).

All of the presentation stuff should be handled on SSRS.

Comment: Since my experience with SSRS is about 2 weeks now, I'm not quite following if I can apply your suggestion to the Chart, I mean it looks like the solution can actually help but I'm not having Matrix as a representation type? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: What Chart you are using?

Comment: The first one from Line type

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Is this SQL Server 2014?

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)
In SQL Server 2014, DATEPART implicitly casts string literals as a datetime2 type. This means that DATEPART does not support the format YDM when the date is passed as a string. You must explicitly cast the string to a datetime or smalldatetime type to use the YDM format.

Answer (score 0):

So following from @nshah suggestion convert the expression to this:

```
=IIF(
  Parameters!date_range.value="Weekly", 
  DATEPART("week", format(Fields!Date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")),  
  DATEPART("month", format(Fields!Date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got the same error as before

Comment: Can it be due to the fact that I'm having 3 charts with 3 sproc's where 1 SP doesn't accepts the date_range argument but returns date column where and I'm forcing SSRS make that grouping by week or month.  And that was my intention for the 2nd chart, where the 3rd chart is using SP that actually accepts @date_range as a parameter (with defaulted to "weekly" defined in SP)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using DATEPART, but I have discovered myself that DATEPART in SSRS does not always work as described in [DATEPART (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datepart-ssis-expression). Here are some examples with specific syntax that worked for me:

- =DATEPART("yyyy", Fields!Date.Value) for year.
- =DATEPART("m", Fields!Date.Value) for month.
- =DATEPART("ww", Fields!Request_Date.Value) for week.